# What is the lifecycle, if any, of c# executable console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am interested to find out if there is any sort of life-cycle of a C# console application, similar to the ASP.Net life-cycle.

I am particularly interested in

- assembly resolution - when does this happen
- compilation - how does the `static Main` method affect compilation of dependant objects

Comment: A console program does not have the same kind of life cycle as a web application. It runs, and then it ends. That's it. But "life cycle" has nothing to do with your other two questions. Also "how does the static Main method affect compilation of dependant objects" is not too clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, each method is JITted as it is first executed, with assembly resolution again happening as-needed, which *usually* means "during JIT of a method that uses an assembly we haven't needed yet" (but can also mean: via reflection).

`static Main` works the same as any other method; anything you use in `Main` will be resolved before `Main` starts executing. In some cases you might want (to help debugging):

```
static int Main(string[] args) {
    try {
        return MainImpl(args);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // .. do something
        return -1;
    }
}
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static int MainImpl(string[] args) { ... }
```

This is useful if the code that would *normally* be in `Main` (but is now in `MainImpl`) is causing assembly resolution errors... since you can't `catch` something in `Main` if `Main` can't first be JITted successfully.

As for life-cycle...

- the entry-point is started (`Main`)
- the application exits when no non-background threads are alive; for a typical linear console exe that means "when `Main` exits", but can be more complex in a threaded server example

  - or it can be terminated prematurely from within or from outside